# PhpStorm: Invocation with class name is deprecated

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, deprecated

When I try to run a test in my PhpStorm I see this:

> PHPUnit 8.5.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>   Warning: Invocation with class name is deprecated

This maybe a issue with how PhpStorm handle the PHPUnit autoloader script and expect to be the filename as same as test.

Any turnaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a warning, you can ignore it for the moment (for PHPUnit 8.5.x at very least).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50201 -- it has been fixed for next PhpStorm versions already (next minor 2019.3.x and next major 2020.1).